# Nginx. Conditionally log a web request that takes more than 3 seconds

Tags: nginx, logging

Is there a way I can conditionally log a web request that takes more than 3 seconds?

Thanks.

Comment: I googled "Nginx Conditional Logging" and found an applicable page. Looks like it can be done using variables, if appropriate variables are available. It's probably worth you looking into. https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/#conditional

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html

Setup a Map and conditional for `$request_time`